# Convert Stream data to custom object in C#.net

Tags: c#

I want to convert stream data from response stream into a custom object.

I want to convert respose stream into custom object,I am following  these steps.

My code is as follows.

```
myMethod()               
{
    state s = new state();
    Stream receiveStream;
    StreamReader readStream;
    HttpWebRequest request;
    HttpWebResponse response;
    try
    {
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url);
        request.Method = "GET";  
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
        receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
        Console.WriteLine (readStream.ReadToEnd());
        serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(state));
        s = serializer.ReadObject(readStream.BaseStream)as state;
        Console.Write(s.name+"\n"); 

        response.Close ();
        readStream.Close ();    

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Object **s** returning nothing.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "returning nothing"? Returning a null reference, or a reference to an object where everything is null? (I'd encourage you to use a cast rather than `as`, by the way.)

Comment: It is returning null reference. I make changes as you told,but still i am getting null reference.

Comment: And what does the data you're receiving look like? (I notice you're setting a request content type, but not actually providing any content, which is odd...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trouble is that you're trying to deserialize an object when you've already read all the data from it just beforehand:

```
readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
Console.WriteLine (readStream.ReadToEnd());
```

After those line, the stream will be empty, so there's nothing to deserialize. Get rid of those lines (then use `receiveStream` below), and you may well find it just works.

Additionally, a few suggestions:

- Rather than closing streams explicitly, use `using` statements
- Add a `using` statement for the response itself, as that implements `IDisposable`
- Keep the scope of each variable as small as it can be, assigning a value at the point of declaration
- It's rarely a good idea to catch `Exception`, and it's almost *never* a good idea to just swallow exceptions in the way that you are doing, with no logging etc
- Follow .NET naming conventions, where `state` would be `State` (and possibly make the name a bit more descriptive anyway)
- Use a cast rather than `as` - see [my blog post on the topic](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions.aspx) for reasons